Issue with GNOME integration of OneDrive in 24.04.1 LTS
A few days ago I booted my Latitude laptop running Windows 10 from the Ubuntu bootable USB. After checking it out, I went to boot back into Windows and Bitlocker prevented me saying something about my Boot security being changed. So, knowing my data was in OneDrive, I deleted the partition and installed Ubuntu, and suddenly I am a new Ubuntu desktop user! However I cannot get OneDrive mount in Files. At one point I successfully added the O365 account, it said File Acces was on, but it would time out trying to mount OneDrive. I deleted the O365 account, and tried re-adding it. When I get to the popup that says "Are you trying to sign into GNOME?" I click to Continue but nothing happens. I can see a post and a get in the network log, but that is it. The goa-auth2 link never pops up, and System freezes and I have to force quit it. Any suggestions?
I am not in love with OneDrive would eventually change it to something more Linux friendly, but for now I really need to mount it. Of course I have access through a web browser but it's a real PITA for me getting back to work. Otherwise I am loving Ubuntu. I do have previous experience with Linux servers but this is my first time using as a desktop with GNOME. Thank you

The GNOME online account version of onedrive is not that useful. Use this instead https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/tree/master

Open a terminal.
Run in it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rclone rclone-browser
rclone config

From the options that appear, select 'n' to add a new remote
Now enter the name of the remote 'Onedrive' is suitable
From the list of services such as cloud storage enter the number of the One Drive service '30'
Press 'Enter' twice, then enter 'N' to select no in the advanced settings, and in 'Use automatic settings' press 'Y'.
Now select the account type, for most users, it is 'One drive Personal or business', which is the '1'.
In the list of 'Drives' associated with your account, it is usually '0' to select your drive and then enter 'Y' for the next step.
To the question if this setting is ok, press 'Y' if it is.
And then enter 'q' to exit the Rclone configuration menu
Next, create the folder where you will mount OneDrive, by running in the terminal:
mkdir ~/onedrive

Now, using this command, you mount One Drive:
rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount Onedrive: ~/onedrive &

You can close the terminal.
Every time you want to mount One Drive, you must run the above command in a terminal.
If you don't want to use the terminal, you can run Rclone Browser, which should be in your menu under Internet applications.
If you prefer it to be mounted at startup and stay that way:
Open 'Startup Applications', click 'Add' and in the command field, enter the following:
sh -c "rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount \Onedrive\: ~/onedrive"


Ok, this is awesome! But I have a little problem. When mounting the drive I received this *Failed to create file system for "Onedrive:": didn't find section in config file

I looked at the rclone.conf and there is a huge auth token and a  drive id and drive type = Onedrive. When I first did this I selected 21 as the type, but that is actually Hadoop so I went back to the rclone config command and then discovered that Onedrive is 30, then I proceeded. Not sure if that had anything to do with it.


I did get a message from Microsoft that rclone connected.

'[OneDrive]
type = onedrive
token = {"access_token":"EwCIA8l6BAAUbDba3x2OMJElkF7gJ4z/A$  some more stuff...$","expiry":"2024-11-29T22:41:24.963258219-05:00"}
drive_id = dbfc1b254c26336a
drive_type = personal'

Success!  It wasjust a typo, as these things usually go. Have to be mmore careful with the character case. Thank yo very much @kyodake
